# Object Destructuring JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm new with JS and I have the next doubt. It's possible to use destructuring with HTML to get attributes? Actually I know this way.

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('script1');
var bar = foo.getAttribute('var1');
var any = foo.getAttribute('var2');
```

```html
<script id="script1" src="code.js" var1="var1" var2="var2">
</script>
```

In my understanding, the way to use object destructuring is:

```
{ var 1, var2 } = foo;
```

But actually I'm getting *undefined* values.

Comment: `var { var1, var2 } = foo;` But you're not going to get anything here because your attributes are non-sandard and thus don't become properties of the element object.

Comment: `var1` is an *attribute*, not a *property* ?

Comment: This isn't html related or are you asking if the scope of destructured declarations is the same as non-destructured ones?

Comment: @AluanHaddad it actually is. The primary missunderstanding here is the difference between attributes and properties.

Comment: @Lux I've changed the tag from `html` to `dom` as that is more accurate.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean

Comment: Technically, if the attributes were correctly prefaced with `data-`, you could destructure the `dataset` property to get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document.getElementById() returns a Element object, which has properties by itself.
This Element object has a property called attributes, which is a NodeValueMap

It is possible to destructure a JavaScript object, however this is not possible for selecting the attributes of the element.